# how to write a regular expression for like ABCD1234?

Tags: regex

I want to set up a rule for a string:
8 chars
first 4 is alphabet, case insensitive.
last 4 is number

how to write a regular expression for this case?

Comment: There is no correlation between `regex` and `regula` (according to Google), so I take `regula` as typo and remove the tag. **Anyway, what is the language?**

Comment: Try writing something yourself and then when it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z]{4}\d{4}$
```

Explanation:

- ^ start of string
- [a-zA-Z] the characters a to z and A to Z
- {4} repeat the list item 4 times
- \d a digit character
- {4} repeat the list item 4 times
- $ end of string